# using two cacscade classifiers for face and eyes detection

Tags: java, android

I'm sorry for the beginner question, but I haven't found the answer.
I'm trying to detect face and eyes at real time. the code (which runs on android openCV) works fine if I use face detection only or eyes detection only, but when I combine both, like in the code attached, the program crashes at run time. I'm not sure how to combine these two cascades (one that displays a rectangle around the face, and another one around the eyes). Any help will be appreciated!

```
    InputStream is3 = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.lbpcascade_frontalface);
        File cascadeDir = context.getDir("cascade", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        File cascadeFile = new File(cascadeDir, "lbpcascade_frontalface.xml");
        File cascadeFileEye = new File(cascadeDir, "eyes_detect.xml");
        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(cascadeFile);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead;

        while ((bytesRead = is3.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            os.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }

        is3.close();
        os.close();
        FileOutputStream os1 = new FileOutputStream(cascadeFileEye);


        byte[] bufferEye = new byte[4096];
        int bytesReadEye;

        while ((bytesReadEye = is3.read(bufferEye)) != -1) {
            os1.write(bufferEye, 0, bytesReadEye);
            }

        is4.close();
        os1.close();

        mCascade = new CascadeClassifier(cascadeFile.getAbsolutePath());
        mCascadeEye = new CascadeClassifier(cascadeFileEye.getAbsolutePath());
        if (mCascade.empty()) {
            //Log.e(TAG, "Failed to load cascade classifier");
            mCascade = null;
            }  

        if (mCascadeEye.empty()) {
            //Log.e(TAG, "Failed to load cascade classifier");
            mCascadeEye = null;
            }  

        cascadeFile.delete();
        cascadeDir.delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the corresponding tutorial from the opencv homepage:

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html#cascade-classifier

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you missing the line

`InputStream is3 = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.eyes_detect);`

You should have the file eyes_detect.xml in your Raw folder also.

I used haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses.xml, and passed only the cropped region of the detected face to get the eye locations.